addEventListner is not calling for First Time
const handleCharacterChange = (value,event) => {
     
        const plainText = value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');
        
        if (plainText?.length <= 250) {
            console.log(plainText,"jkldnaslkndlkas")
            setText(value)
        }else{
            console.log("aklsndakslmdlamsdlasmd  else ")
            document.getElementById("quill")?.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => handlePasteData(e));
        }
}

The Event Listener isn't calling the first time
if user input exceeded from the max value it should prevent function

Hello Talha, welcome to stackoverflow. Have you considered that you are not checking whether or not the HTMLElement 'Quill' exists? Right now, the eventlistener is added to either null or HTMLElement. Try adding a condition to see if 'quill' exists on the DOM, then if it does, add the event listener.

When, where, and how is handleCharacterChange () called?

Hi, Can you please help us to know your respective code snippet, which prevents the use input exceeding the limit ? What is clear to me from your code is that, when the input is not exceeding, then a state is updated. What is to be understood more is that the else part - what it does at the moment ?

There are following issues in your code:
1- You are not checking whether element with id 'quill' exists in DOM or not before adding eventListner.
2- You are attaching eventListner again and again if words limit exceeded.
YOUR MAIN ISSUE:
3- You are registering eventListner when limit exceeds so it doesn't capture the current event because not registered before hand. In technical terms, the keydown event listener is only added after your else block is executed, so it's too late for it to catch the keypress that caused the limit to be exceeded.
SOLUTION:
Attach the eventListner on initial render like in useEffect then check for limit on each keydown this way it works when limit reaches.
NOTE:
if you follow this approach which is registering eventListner initially in useEffect then it takes initial value of your state named text not the updated value so you have to use Ref instead of state or use both state and ref but make them sync to solve that issue.
if you have further queries or need code snippet for this let me know.
Happy coding :)
